# WPF .Net Core and PopupWindowAction

Tags: wpf, prism

Can anyone suggest a pattern to open/manage popup windows in a WPF MVVM(Prism) `.Net Core` application? I was using Prism's `PopupWindowAction` before. Now XAML `Behaviors` for WPF are ported to `.Net Core` (https://weekly-geekly.github.io/articles/433334/index.html), but `Interaction.Triggers` doesn't accept `InteractionRequestTrigger`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called `IDialogService`, see this issue at [Github](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1666).